# Unknown mysql cell entry

Tags: php, mysql

Ive recently purchases a script from a website and I was going through the code to see how it inserts and extracts data from mysql... there's this one cell in a table title "issue_date" has just numerical values in it and I am not familiar with this date format, the other column "expiry_date" is the same. Here are the values in the mysql cells "issue_date" [1565481600] and "expiry date" [1568073600]. on the frontend page these numbers translate in to today's (issue) date + 350 days (expiry) date. **I need help with identifying the format these numbers are in. Thanks.**

Comment: They're Unix Timestamps.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! You might want to go through this link so that your questions receieve good attention and possibly not get down voted :) - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It is in timestamp format.
A timestamp is a numeric value in seconds between the current time and value as at 1st January, 1970 00:00:00 Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).
The value returned by the time function depends on the default time zone.
visit https://www.guru99.com/php-date-functions.html
[Check time value of time in human readable form](https://www.timestampconvert.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The format is a [Unix Time Stamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

[Here](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/)'s a good website to convert given Unix Time stamp to human readable format, and back.